# How would I go about designing this in a database

Tags: database-design

At this point I am confused and am just looking for people to bounce this off of and so you guys are it.

I am working on a web based inventory program for our organization.

At this point I want it to be as generic as possible so I am looking at a structure like this:

[image]

So what I am looking at is there are item types or categories, each Item type has a set of properties and properties can be shared, each item has an item type which then gives the item properties that can be filled with values, these values then have to relate back to the properties.

Does this make sense to anyone else? I am confused to no avail at this point so any thoughts or suggestions or even reading material that would put me in the right general direction would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The diagram could be clearer by showing cardinality of the relationships involved. But I get what the design basically is.

It's called an "entity-attribute-value" model, aka an "open schema", and it's not an uncommon thing to do in a database. However, you should be aware that there are significant downsides to this approach:

- validation of properties and their types by the RDBMS becomes much more difficult
- queries retrieving property values for a particular entity are more complicated
- it's harder to reason about that entity using just database queries

In sum, you are going to have to have your application, or maybe stored procedures, do a bunch of work managing these properties, as the database is not going to be able to give you much support besides pure storage and lookup.

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model for a pretty good rundown on when this design might be a good idea. Also check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner-platform_effect on why it might be a bad one. You'll have to decide for your application whether this is the right approach for you.

If what you want to do is provide persistence for objects, I should note that this is a problem that *object-oriented databases* try to solve in a more natural manner. If you're really frustrated by this design, and you're free to look at whatever DBMS might solve the problem, you might look into that.

Comment: This helped significantly. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I see an ItemTypes table which defines the types (type id, type name); a Properties table that defines the properties (property id, property name); an ItemTypeProperties table which lists the properties that apply for each type (i.e., item type id, property id); an Items table which lists the items and their types (item id, item type); and an ItemProperties table which lists the values of the properties for each item (i.e., item id, property id, value).

Does this make sense?